# Android make view height 50% of screen width

Tags: android

I wish to make a view with the width to be match_parent, but the height to be 50% of the width.

How do I do it?

Is the only way to do it through java code inside the activity? I'll have to read the screen width and set the height that way.

Comment: If that answer solve your problem please accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve any aspect ratio you want using ConstraintLayout.

To set up ConstraintLayout follow this: [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project).
Then you can do something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,2:1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Cool this is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**For better look experience and easy implementation** I recommend you to simply add a `Space` or another widget invisible in the center of a `RelativeLayout`, then add the views you need respecting that `Space` or invisible widget.

For example there's a `listView` in the middle-top and another `RelativeLayout` in the middle-bottom with you requirements:

[image]

Also you can easily change to:

[image]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCenterInvisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/leftListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCenterInvisible"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewCenterTopSecondLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Text in Second Layout Center Top" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewCenterSecondLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/coins"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCenterTopSecondLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Button of second layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just play with the aligns.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically by extending the view class the are you using and override the OnMeasure method like below:

```
public class HalfHeightTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public HalfHeightTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HalfHeightTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HalfHeightTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //We take the measured height and set half of it as height
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec/2);
    }
}
```

Then you should use it that way in your layout

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.android.sunshine.utilities.HalfHeightTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="This is a test"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this way, hope this will help you.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int s_width = size.x;
```

here s_width is your Device Screen width, now you can pass  `match_parent` as width of your `view` and `(s_width/2)` as height of View.

Answer (score -1):

```
try it.
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
```